# PHP mail with attachment no errors

Tags: php

My web server supports mail() function. I do not see any errors. But My email does not get the email. I tried so many things in SO and Google.

```
     <?php
    //error_reporting(-1);
    //ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    //set_error_handler("var_dump");

    $to = "raveen_chandra@yahoo.com";
    $subject = "New attachment message";

    $msg = "This is headline";
    $message .= "This is my first line of text.\nThis is my second line of text";

    $fileatt = "uploads/3.JPG";
    $fo = fopen( $fileatt, 'r' );
    $data = fread( $fo, filesize($fileatt) ); //read entire file
    fclose( $fo );
    $data = chunk_split( base64_encode($data) ); //?????? what is chunk_split and base64_encode

    //generate a boundary
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time())); //md5() is used to create unique number
    $filename = basename( $fileatt );

    //main header (multipart mandatory)
    $header = "From: Raveen Chandra <raveen1231@gmail.com> \r\n";
    //$header .= "Cc: raveen749@gmail.com \r\n";
    //$header .= "Bcc: raveen678@gmail.com \r\n";
    //$header .= "Reply-to: raveen_chandra@yahoo.com \r\n"; //can be same address as From header or other
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"". $uid. "\"\r\n"; //to send an email with attachment, we need to use the multipart/mixed MIME type
                                             //it specifies that mixed types will be included in the email

    /* message and attachment - message and attachment sections can be specified within boundaries.
    */
    $message = "--". $uid. "\r\n"; //boundary starts with two hyphens, followed by a unique number 
    $message .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; //Content-type: text/plain;
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $msg. "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--". $uid. "\r\n"; //When sending multiple attachments, separate MIME parts with this
    $message .= "Content-type: image/jpeg; name\"". $filename. "\"\r\n"; //use different content types here
    $message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"". $filename. "\"\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= $data. "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= "--". $uid. "--"; //after the final MIME part

    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $header) ){
        echo "Message sent successfully";
    }
    else{
        echo "Message could not be sent!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Uncomment the first three lines to check what error are you getting `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: @Uchiha, sir I unchecked. Then I got lot of errors full of page difficult to read. one thing... int(8) string(27) "Undefined variable: message" string(33) . then I corrected:) then I get no errors. but still I get no email

Comment: I do not understand . sorry. What am I doing? please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can check in spam.

and for kind of your information please

$to = "raveen_chandra@yahoo.com"; //It's wrong way.
  $to = "mymail@yahoo.com"; //It's good
 way.